# You don’t have permission to save the file “project.pbxproj”

Tags: swift, xcode

I am reading `project.pbxproj` of a random Xcode project and after reading and applying my logic to read data I want update it to my edit version. I am opening it as a txt file and trying save new version again with this code:

```
do {
    try finalString.write(to: pbxprojURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
}
catch(let error) {
    print("Error writing \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Then Xcode complain about:

`You don’t have permission to save the file “project.pbxproj” in the folder “TEST 25.xcodeproj”.`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can change a file permission from your app without asking the user permission.

Comment: @LeoDabus: If this issue could be solved with asking the user permission I am 100% okay with it. But Xcode or macOS did not pop up a permission question.

Comment: Try asking the user to select the file you are editing. I think you will need to add this file type to your app (info > document types)

Comment: @LeoDabus: I tried your advice in first place to target the `25.xcodeproj` from fileImporter but there is no such `*.xcodeproj` available as UTType. plus the issue would not solved because I need to build  project.pbxproj url by myself after selecting `25.xcodeproj` PS: I also tried to add xcodeproj type in document types, but no success in results I mean I add it but fileImporter did not accept it. May I could done some mistake as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Ensure that App Sandbox is disabled and try running your app again. You can find this option under the Capabilities tab in the project configuration/ settings*

> As you can see from the image below, there are options for File `Permission and Access`. You don't need to worry about these. Just turn the whole 'App Sandbox' Capability off.

[image: App Sandbox Capability]

Comment: Thanks, But the target Xcode project that I am going update it is an iOS project! there is no Sandbox there to turning on or off.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a user permission privilege issue. Have you checked the 'Sharing and Permissions' of the “TEST 25.xcodeproj” or main root folder. You can find this by right clicking on the folder in Finder > Get Info > Sharing and Permissions. Ensure that you have both 'Read and Write' access.

Comment: I did the work you said, still does not allow we to update. :( Maybe there is some stronger way that really allow to update.

Comment: Did you also check the permissions under the main root folder (which holds all of the files)? Otherwise, perhaps try cleaning the build folder - ⌘ + shift + k

Comment: Can you help me about: `the permissions under the main root folder` I just right clicked on  `TEST 25.xcodeproj` and did the work you said.

Comment: Check the user permissions for the folder that holds the `TEST 25.xcodeproj`. For example: **My App Folder** > TEST 25.xcodeproj. Change/ check the permissions for the *My App Folder*. With any Xcode Project, there is a **main** folder that holds the . xcodeproj file and another folder for all of the Swift files, etc. You need to check the permissions for the folder that holds all of these project files/ sub-folders together.

Comment: I also did that one, still same issue. :(

Comment: Create a new Xcode Project with the same name as your current project/ app, then copy the info.plist file from the new app. Delete the info.plist file in your old project and paste in the new info.plist into the old project. *I would suggest keeping the old one somewhere safe instead of deleting it just in case*

Comment: Yes, but the project is created with Xcode 13.0+ so there is no actual plist like old time around with Xcode 12.0+ or lower. that is the issue.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is whether or not you have set a key for the `CFBundleExecutable` in the info.plist. If you find it remove it.

Comment: I did not edit or change `CFBundleExecutable`, it is as default from begining.

Comment: I have an idea, but not sure how could be possible! I was thinking reading  `TEST 25.xcodeproj` components then creating new and wished `project.pbxproj` and packaging it again with old untouched components as new file/folder/holder, then delete `TEST 25.xcodeproj` then rename new one to `TEST 25.xcodeproj`